# IOS , save the sate data and restore it when comes back from another view controller

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

I am programming some textfield which allow user input data and update data.user could input data and click save button to save, when user click update button,the information just right appears on the textfield for user to edit. but in one textfield , user has to click a beside button which direct user to another new view controller, and while user comes back to the old view controller, all the edited information has gone. I know it is because the global variable has been cleaned. Is there any way to save the data state and restore it after comes back from other view controllers. Thanks very much!!!!!!!!

here is the code I am using(I am using sqlite to store the information):

```
import Foundation

class DeliveryInfoVC: UIViewController,UITableViewDelegate,UITableViewDataSource {


    @IBOutlet weak var addressLabel: UITextField!

    @IBOutlet weak var phoneLabel: UITextField!

    @IBOutlet weak var nickNameLabel: UITextField!

    @IBOutlet weak var tableView: UITableView!

    var userID:Int=0

    var address=[String]()

    var deliverDataObject:[DeliverDataObject]=[]

    var deliverInfoDBHandler=DeliverInfoDBHandler()

    var isInUpdate:Bool=false

    var buttonColor:UIColor=UIColor.yellowColor()

    var accountID:Int64=0

    @IBAction func addNewAdd(sender: AnyObject) {


    }

    @IBAction func infoSave(sender: AnyObject) {
        if phoneLabel.text=="" || addressLabel.text=="" {

            let alert = UIAlertController(title: "Can not save the data", message:   "Please input the contact number or address", preferredStyle: UIAlertControllerStyle.Alert)
            alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "OK", style: UIAlertActionStyle.Default, handler: nil))
            self.presentViewController(alert, animated: true, completion: nil)


        }else if isInUpdate{


            deliverInfoDBHandler.UpdatedelivertableData(accountID, address_NickName: nickNameLabel.text!, delivery_Address: addressLabel.text!, contact_Number: phoneLabel.text!, is_InUpdate: false)

            addressLabel.text=""
            phoneLabel.text=""
            nickNameLabel.text=""
            address=[]
            self.viewDidLoad()
            tableView.reloadData()

        }else{


            let rowid = deliverInfoDBHandler.SetdelivertableData(userID, address_NickName: nickNameLabel.text!, delivery_Address: addressLabel.text!, contact_Number: phoneLabel.text!, is_InUpdate: false)
            print(rowid)
            deliverDataObject=deliverInfoDBHandler.GetdelivertableData(userID)

            tableView.reloadData()

            addressLabel.text=""
            phoneLabel.text=""
            nickNameLabel.text=""
        }

    }


    override func viewDidLoad() {
        tableView.dataSource = self
        tableView.delegate = self

        let prefs:NSUserDefaults = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults()
        userID=prefs.integerForKey("USERID")

        addressLabel.text=address.joinWithSeparator(",")
        print(address)
        deliverInfoDBHandler.ConnectionandCreatingTable()

        deliverDataObject=deliverInfoDBHandler.GetdelivertableData(userID)

    }


    func tableView(tableView: UITableView, commitEditingStyle editingStyle: UITableViewCellEditingStyle, forRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {

        if editingStyle == UITableViewCellEditingStyle.Delete {


            let rowid=deliverDataObject[indexPath.row].deliverAccountID
            deliverDataObject.removeAtIndex(indexPath.row)

            tableView.deleteRowsAtIndexPaths([indexPath], withRowAnimation: UITableViewRowAnimation.Automatic)
            deliverInfoDBHandler.DeletedelivertableRowData(rowid)
            tableView.reloadData()
        }

    }

    func numberOfSectionsInTableView(tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
        return 1

    }

    func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return deliverDataObject.count
    }

    func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("cell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! DeliveryInfoCell

        cell.savedaddLabel.text = deliverDataObject[indexPath.row].address
        cell.cellNickLabel.text = deliverDataObject[indexPath.row].addressNickName
        cell.updateButton.tag = indexPath.row
        cell.updateButton.addTarget(self, action: #selector(DeliveryInfoVC.UpdateButtonClicked(_:)), forControlEvents:  UIControlEvents.TouchUpInside)
        cell.updateButton.backgroundColor=buttonColor
        return cell
    }

    func UpdateButtonClicked(sender:UIButton){

        let buttonRow = sender.tag

        addressLabel.text = deliverDataObject[buttonRow].address
        phoneLabel.text = deliverDataObject[buttonRow].contactNo
        nickNameLabel.text = deliverDataObject[buttonRow].addressNickName
        buttonColor = UIColor.redColor()
        isInUpdate = true
        deliverDataObject[buttonRow].isInUpdate=true
        accountID = deliverDataObject[buttonRow].deliverAccountID
        tableView.reloadData()
    }


}
```

Comment: Some visual explanation would help.

Comment: It isn't very clear. Update your answer with more info

Comment: just done with it thanks！

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem you have is that you do not have **persistent storage**. In iOS, if something is not stored on the device, it can be lost easily once you leave the View Controller.

More precisely, variables lose their values when the object that holds them is deallocated, or when their value is explicitly altered one way or another.

Certain segue types, for example, can create a new instance of a VC, resulting in a loss of data. Storing a value permanently allows one to bypass these issues.

In terms of persistent storage, there are several options:

> 1) Using an online database (though WiFi is required)
>
> 2) Using NSUserDefaults (easy persistent storage for fairly small information: avoid images)
>
> 3) Core Data (on-device persistent storage: more complicated but much more powerful)

I would recommend beginning with NSUserDefaults, since this is easy to learn.

Here is how you can write to NSUserDefaults:

In this example, I am using an array of Strings to explain, but the same applies to any other form of data.

```
let defaults = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults()
defaults.setObject(myArray, forKey: "arrayKey")
```

And this is how you can retrieve the data:

```
var retrievedArray = defaults.objectForKey("arrayKey") as [String]
```

I am assuming it is an array of strings.
So when you add data to the array, store it in NSUserDefaults, then, when you need to retrieve the data, take it from there.

In addition, this will allow you to access this information in other ViewControllers as well as after an app has been terminated. In other words, the data is there to stay. You can still overwrite it of course, as well as remove it by deleting the app.

For more info, take a look at this:
https://www.hackingwithswift.com/read/12/2/reading-and-writing-basics-nsuserdefaults

Good luck!

Comment: No problem @QiLee !